# Running multiple program one in sequence does not understand '-parameter' in Perl or shell script

Tags: perl

I have to run many programs one after another with the ouput of each program as the input of the next.

I have tried with Perl using `system` as well as a shell script, but it does not understand `-parameter`.

Here is my script, please help me to solve this. I am working on Ubuntu.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename='';

print "\nEnter file name: ";
$filename=<STDIN>;

system("/usr/local/RepeatMasker/RepeatMasker –species rice $filename");
system("rm $filename.out, $filename.cat, $filename.tbl");
system("/usr/local/blast-2.2.25/bin/blastall –p blastx –i $filename.masked –d ../../database/RGAP-all.pep –o $filename.m.blx");
system("/usr/local/Genomescan/blastx2genoa $filename.m.blx –m /usr/local/Genomescan/BLOSUM62 >$filename.m.genoa");
system("/usr/local/Genomescan/genomescan  /usr/local/Genomescan/genomescan-pm/Maize.smat $filename.masked –g $filename.m.genoa –ps $filename.ps >$filename.out");

Print "Done";
```

When I run this, it takes `-species` as a filename and does not understand `-i` or `-p`.

Comment: Does `/usr/local/RepeatMasker/RepeatMasker –species rice myfile` work on the command line? If it's not working in a shell script then it sounds like you're not using `RepeatMasker` properly

Answer (score 0):

Your `system` commands are kind of ugly (please consider using [multi-argument system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)), but there's no reason why they wouldn't "understand parameters".

However, I do see several other bugs in your code:

- You don't `chomp $filename` after reading it, so it will end in a newline character.  This means that e.g. `"$filename.out"` will evaluate to something like `"whatever\n.out"`, which the shell will parse as two separate arguments, as if it read `"whatever .out"`.
- Also, arguments to shell commands are separated by whitespace, not commas.  Thus, the commas in your `rm` command are interpreted as part of the file names to delete.  (But since you probably don't have any files named `.out,` or `.cat,` anyway, it doesn't make any difference until you fix the first bug above.)

  (You don't really need to call `rm` anyway.  Perl has a perfectly good built-in `unlink` command.)
- Since you use the single-argument form of `system`, your command string will be parsed by the shell.  This means that, even after you fix the newline issue, any spaces or other shell metacharacters in the file name will break your code.  You should either switch to multi-argument `system` (which bypasses the shell) or use [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String%3a%3aShellQuote).

Anyway, it looks like you're really trying to write a shell script in Perl.  Why not just make it an honest shell script?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -ep "Enter file name: " filename

/usr/local/RepeatMasker/RepeatMasker –species rice "$filename"
rm "$filename.out" "$filename.cat" "$filename.tbl"
/usr/local/blast-2.2.25/bin/blastall –p blastx –i "$filename.masked" –d ../../database/RGAP-all.pep –o "$filename.m.blx"
/usr/local/Genomescan/blastx2genoa "$filename.m.blx" –m /usr/local/Genomescan/BLOSUM62 >"$filename.m.genoa"
/usr/local/Genomescan/genomescan /usr/local/Genomescan/genomescan-pm/Maize.smat "$filename.masked" –g "$filename.m.genoa" –ps "$filename.ps" >"$filename.out"

echo "Done."
```

This will not only yield cleaner code, but will fix most if not all of the issues described above automatically:

- The bash `read` command automatically strips the trailing newline from the input.
- Since the shell is now doing the variable interpolation by itself, we can safely use double quotes around the file names to tell it to consider each filename a single argument, even if `$filename` happens to contain whitespace or other special characters.